# How to auto hide row with condition? Google sheets with GAS

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have range of cell `A:G`. How can the row automatically hide if column `A:A` have value (for example if `A1:A1000` have value and `A1001:A` is blank then hide `A1:A980`&`A1001:A` I only need data in the last 20 row).

Because i'm importrange form another sheet, and now it too long.

```
function hideRow(){
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("ID");
var s = ss.getSheetByName("1");      
var row = s.getRange('A:A').getValues();     
s.showRows(1, s.getMaxRows());
for(var i=0; i< row.length; i++){ if(row[i] == 'OK') { s.hideRows(i+1, 1); }   // Value to hide
}}
```

I have that code, but it only hide if value is `OK` (Column A is date) and will be hide everything. Thank for reading :d.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of hiding rows, wrap your `importrange()` in a `query()` to filter out the rows you do not need. You can do that by sorting the data by a timestamp column with `order by` and then `limit` the result to 20 rows. See the [query()](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3093343) help page.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot, I just ```Importrange()``` from ```A:F``` and column ```G:G``` to add values.

Comment: You should not be "adding values" to an imported range. Always add additional data directly to the source spreadsheet. See Lance's treatment of the [row misalignment](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/95901649) issue.

Comment: My data is from google forms and is not allowed to be modified. Sorted by timestamp, so everything should be fine. Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: That should work, as long as you never delete or insert any rows in the form responses sheet. Timestamps have a resolution of one millisecond, so it is a pretty stable sort key. To best get help with your original question, please share a publicly editable [sample spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/269219) with realistic-looking data.